update supabase public.users table from nextjs 15 api route handler
I have a nextjs 15 application hooked up to supabase. One of my components, EditAccount.tsx looks like this:
'use client';

/* imports */

const StyledForm = styled(Form)`
  height: 70%;
  padding-left: 10%;
  gap: 2rem;
`;

type AccountDetailsProps = {
  accountDetails: UserAccount | null;
}

const EditAccount: React.FC<AccountDetailsProps> = ({ accountDetails }: AccountDetailsProps): JSX.Element => {
  /* useState, useForm hooks */

  const { accessToken } = useAuth();

  useEffect(() => {
    setToken(accessToken ?? '');
  }, [accessToken]);

  const handleClickShowPassword = () => setShowPassword(!showPassword);
  const handleMouseDownPassword = (event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement>) => event.preventDefault();

  const getChangedData = (data: UserAccount) => {
    const changedData: Partial<UserAccount> = {};
    
    { /* ...... */ }

    return changedData;
  };

  const onSubmit: SubmitHandler<UserAccount> = async (data) => {
    setLoading(true);

    const payload = getChangedData(data);

    try {
      const response = await axios.patch('/api/update-account', payload, {
        headers: {
          'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`,
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
      });

      if (response.status === 200) {
        setModalText('Profile successfully updated.');
        setModalInstructions('');
        setLoading(false);
        reset();
        setRedirect('');
        setIsModalOpen(true);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error updating account:', error);
      if (axios.isAxiosError(error) && error.response) {
        console.error('Response data:', error.response.data);
        console.error('Response status:', error.response.status);
        console.error('Response headers:', error.response.headers);
      }
    }
    setLoading(false);
  };

  const selectedCountry = useWatch({
    control,
    name: 'country',
    defaultValue: accountDetails?.country
  });

  const notUS = selectedCountry !== 'United States';

  return (
    loading ? <CircularSpinner /> :
    <>
      <StyledForm action='/' onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
        <Stack>

        { /* ..... */ }

          <LifestyleFormButton>
            SUBMIT
          </LifestyleFormButton>
          <Divider />
          <Link href='/account/delete'>
            <Typography variant='body2'>
              Delete Account
            </Typography>
          </Link>
        </Stack>
      </StyledForm>
      <LifestyleModal
        isOpen={isModalOpen}
        text={modalText}
        instructions={modalInstructions}
        redirect={redirect}
      />
    </>
  );
}

export default EditAccount;

This triggers the api route at /api/update-account/, shown here:
import { createSupabaseClient } from '@/utils/supabase/server';
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from 'next/server';

export const PATCH = async (req: NextRequest) => {
  try {
    const supabase = await createSupabaseClient();

    const authHeader = req.headers.get('Authorization');

    const token = authHeader?.split(' ')[1];

    if (!token) return NextResponse.json({ error: 'Unauthorized: No access token provided' }, { status: 401 });
    
    const { data: { user }, error: authError } = await supabase.auth.getUser(token);

    if (authError) return NextResponse.json({ error: 'Unauthorized: Invalid access token' }, { status: 401 });

    const body = await req.json();

    const { email, password, ...profileData } = body;

    console.log(profileData);

    if (email || password) {
      const { error: authUpdateError } = await supabase.auth.updateUser({ email, password });
      if (authUpdateError) return NextResponse.json({ error: authUpdateError.message }, { status: 400 });
    }

    const { data: updatedProfile, error: profileUpdateError } = await supabase
      .from('public.users')
      .update(profileData)
      .eq('id', user?.id).select('*');

    console.log(updatedProfile);

    if (profileUpdateError) return NextResponse.json({ error: profileUpdateError.message }, { status: 400 });


    if (!updatedProfile) return NextResponse.json({ error: 'No data returned from update operation.' }, { status: 500 });

    return NextResponse.json({ success: true, data: updatedProfile }, { status: 200 });
  } catch (error) {
    const errorMessage = error instanceof Error ? error.message : 'An unknown error occurred.';
    return NextResponse.json({ error: errorMessage }, { status: 500 });
  }
};


I can't get past the const { data: updatedProfile, error: profileUpdateError } = await supabase... line. When I print console.log(updatedProfile), I get null. How can I update the table? The policy on it is this:
on "public"."users"

to authenticated

using (
  (auth.uid() = id)
);

The actual error is status code 400 (AxiosError {message: 'Request failed with status code 400', name: 'AxiosError', code: 'ERR_BAD_REQUEST', config: {…}, request: XMLHttpRequest, …})
I've done all the normal logging to make sure the right token exists, the body of the request is correct (e.g., updating phone in public.users, the body is { phone: '15555555555' }. Any help is appreciated!
